# Object is a null reference only when using a method?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a object called "target" with a property called "movement":

```
private function start() {
var movement:IMovement = new ZigZagMovement(target);
target.movement = movement;
mediumDifficulty();
}

private function mediumDifficulty(target:AbstractTarget):void {

            var movement:IMovement = target.movement;
            movement.mediumMove();
        }
```

My Abstract Target class looks like this:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class AbstractTarget extends Sprite
    {
        protected var __movement:IMovement;

        public function AbstractTarget()
        {
        }

        public function set movement(value:IMovement):void
        {
            __movement = value;
        }

        public function get movement():IMovement
        {
            return __movement;
        }


    }
}
```

My "movement" class looks like this:

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ZigZagMovement implements IMovement
        {
            private var __target:Object;

            public function ZigZagMovement(target:Object)
            {
                __target = target;
            }



            public function mediumMove():void
            {
                // movement code
            }


        }
    }
```

The weird thing is when I trace "target" and "target.movement" I get what I am looking for...but if I try to say, write:

```
target.movement.mediumMove();
```

OR

`movement.mediumMove()`;

Then both the target and "movement" (local variable) trace out to null??

Answer (score 1):

I think we need more information.  There are some things I'm not seeing in the code sample or explanation:

- What is the concrete object you're passing to the mediumDifficulty function?  It is clearly not ZigZagMovement, as that is the movement member variable of the AbstractTarget.
- When are you instantiating the concrete subclass of AbstractTarget?  What is the specific subclass of AbstractTarget?  You didn't post any code for it.  Are you sure it actually has instantiated a movement object by the time it's passed to the mediumDifficulty function?

It sounds like what's happening is that AbstractTarget subclass you're testing in isolation has an IMovement, but not the one you're passing to the mediumDifficulty function, but without more information it's difficult to say.

(Setting this as a community wiki in case I'm missing something)

EDIT: With the new information --

It appears that you have a class-level variable called "target" that you're assigning your movement to, and that you also have a param named "target" in your mediumDifficulty() function signature, and that you're not actually passing your class-level target object into the function.  What this results in is that when mediumDifficulty tries to ascertain the value of target, it's null because it's looking at the param and not the class-level variable.  That's possibly how you can manage to trace target and target.movement in the start() function but not get any values in mediumDifficulty.

Try in the future to have function params or function scoped variables *not* share names with class-scoped vars to cut down on this kind of confusion.

Comment: I added more detail...I apologize about the formatting, can't seem to get it right in this editor.

Comment: Hmm... If the code listed is complete, then it appears that you're not actually passing anything to mediumDifficulty();  That would explain why the target object is null (and of course then also why its movement is null).   You're doing it right by calling movement.mediumMove() (that's what interfaces are for), but I think your input into mediumDifficulty(); is what's wrong.